# create dictionary with arguments

Tags: c#

I want to create a control panel for simple robots. There are some commands I can use

- MOV F 3 - Move forward three units
- MOV B 7 - Move backwards seven units
- TRN L - Rotate to the left by fifteen degrees
- TRN R - Rotate to the right by fifteen degrees
- RCK - Collect
- RLS - Drop
- ALS - Analyse
- PIC - Take a picture
- LOG - Show the command history

I started creating it **(some error handling is missing here)**

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] inputSegments = input.Split();
        string commandSegment = inputSegments[0];

        switch (commandSegment)
        {
            case "MOV":
                string movementDirectionSegment = inputSegments[1];
                string movementRangeSegment = inputSegments[2];
                int unitsToMove = Convert.ToInt32(movementRangeSegment);

                if (movementDirectionSegment == "F")
                {
                    Move(true, unitsToMove);
                }
                else if (movementDirectionSegment == "B")
                {
                    Move(false, unitsToMove);
                }
                else
                {
                    // wrong parameters
                }
                break;

            case "TRN":
                string rotationSegment = inputSegments[1];

                if (rotationSegment == "L")
                {
                    Rotate(false);
                }
                else if (rotationSegment == "R")
                {
                    Rotate(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    // wrong parameters
                }
                break;

            case "RCK":
                Collect();
                break;

            case "RLS":
                Drop();
                break;

            case "ANL":
                Analyse();
                break;

            case "PIC":
                TakePicture();
                break;

            case "LOG":
                ShowCommandHistory();
                break;

            case "HLP":
                ShowCommands();
                break;

            default:
                // Command not found
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I thought about replacing the switch with a dictionary for the commands. My first try was

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Action> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
    {
        { "MOV", Move },
        { "TRN", Rotate },
        { "RCK", Collect },
        { "RLS", Drop },
        { "ANL", Analyse },
        { "PIC", TakePicture },
        { "LOG", ShowCommandHistory },
        { "HLP", ShowCommands },
    };
```

But as you know `Move` and `Rotate` take some parameters

```
    private static void Move(bool moveForward, int units)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private static void Rotate(bool rotateRight)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

and the parameters like `F` need to get validated. A valid `KeyValuePair<string, Action>` would be

```
{ "MOV {x} {y}", Move(x, y) } // x can be F or B, y is an integer
```

Is there something I can use? Using a switch is fine but I think there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the processing of arguments *inside* each command method. Then your dictionary will look like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string[]>> commands = …;
```

You will end up with better encapsulation of commands' logic.